# Typescrpit | method

Tags: typescript

error: onSearchChange and placeholder not exist on type PageHeaderProps , how is possible i added 2 options

```
 type PageHeaderPropsBase = {
      title: string;
      subTitle?: string;
    };
    
    type PageHeaderPropsWithSearch = PageHeaderPropsBase & {
      onSearchChange: (text: string) => void;
      placeholder: string;
    };
    
    type PageHeaderProps = PageHeaderPropsBase | PageHeaderPropsWithSearch;
    
    export default function PageHeader({
      title,
      subTitle,
      onSearchChange,
      placeholder,
    }: PageHeaderProps)
```

Comment: Given that `PageHeaderPropsWithSearch` _already_ includes `PageHeaderPropsBase`, what exactly is the point of `PageHeaderProps`?

Answer (score 0):

You can and should do `: PageHeaderPropsBase` if you know it is this certain type already, which you are saying it is in the declaration.
The typescript is complaining because `PageHeaderPropsBase` type doesn't include the properties you want it to have. The `|` doesn't mean `excluding or` but `inclusive or` in this scenario.

For your example to work with the type you want you would need to do:

```
export default function PageHeader(parameter: PageHeaderProps) {...}
```